# Facebook like swipe menus in JavaScript without jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript

I'm developing an app with **PhoneGap** and **jQuery Mobile.** It is truly killing the performance of application.The only reason I'm using jQuery Mobile is because of the [swipe lateral menus](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/examples/panels/panel-swipe-open.html).

There is any **simple** library that does that implementation correctly? I only found jQuery Mobile related things.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try these two projects as well

https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js

http://www.berriart.com/sidr/

Comment: Can't we just use HTML 5 for this. I don't know for sure, but heard some people saying this can be achieved using HTML 5 only. If this is the case, why use any external library to increase the size and dependency of the project?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cool one written using Javascript. You can try this:

https://github.com/boxbreakout/menujs

Comment: @udexter-you can go with javascript suggested by Geeniewanted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,You are right,They are causing many performance issues for the application mainly,

1.Due to the fact that there are transitions effects for whenever we swipe something or change the current Page.Every mobile devices are not compatible enough for the transitions.So,to make it working smooth apply transitions to none everywhere in your application.

Apply this into your index.html page.In head tag.

```
<script>
 $(document).on("mobileinit", function()
  {
        $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
  }
</script>
```

or

you can apply `data-transition="none"` into your application.
I have similar issue in past.But this solution worked for me.

2.I don't know any javascript library.but i have one solutions for this.Take one div and make it hide/show on `mousemove/touchmove` or `swipeleft/swiperight` events of jQuery Mobile.You can set the CSS of the div to show/hide anywhere in your page.

Here is the link for the number of events of jQM.
[jQM Events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html)

e.g.

```
 <div id="xyz">
 </div>

 <a data-role="button" id="abc" href="#" data-theme="c" >Swiperight</a>
```

in javaScript

```
 $('#abc').on('swipeleft',function()
 {
    var div = $('#xyz');
    div.show();
 }
```

Hope i have answered your question as per your requirements.