# Swipe table cell vertical menu

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, menu

I am developing a app and I want to create a swappable menu.
I have found some libraries like `MCSwipeTableViewCell`.

The problem with these libraries is that I am not be able to add a vertical menu, only a horizontal menu.

How am I able to develop a swipable menu (see screenshot).

Any help is welcome :-)

**Screenshot:**
[image: Screensnap]

Comment: Why is this question too broad? I am asking for something specific. How can I improve my question?

Comment: Do you mean **swipe menu**? Please see this question, it may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556665/facebook-like-swipe-menus-in-javascript-without-jquery-mobile

Comment: Semantic UI also have similar widget: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html

Comment: Kinda, but I want to have a swipe menu in a table cell like you see in the screenshot. 3 icons will apear when you swipe from right to left.

Comment: Also, Take a look at the tags. I am not mentioning html/css but Objective-C

Answer (score 1):

Well I know its kinda late. Since this was left unanswered ...
Have a look at this [library](https://github.com/srikanth-vm/GSSwipeableCell). <strike>As of now only portrait mode is supported.</strike>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`MCSwipeTableViewCell` gives you a `UITableViewCell` subclass with up to four swipe options (that is, buttons that are revealed when swiping either left or right on the cell). I'm sure you're already aware of this.

`MCSwipeTableViewCell` implements only horizontal swipe-buttons. That is, you could provide a view with three vertically arranged buttons (corresponding to your requirements) as one of the swipe-buttons in a cell instance's `setSwipeGestureWithView:color:mode:state:completionBlock:` method, but then you wouldn't be able to tell which button was pressed. I suppose you want to know which vertical button was tapped.

However, creating a swipeable cell is not that difficult. You could seek inspiration in `MCSwipeTableViewCell`'s implementation (it is open source after all). A good place to start could be the [`handlePanGestureRecognizer:`](https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell/blob/master/MCSwipeTableViewCell/MCSwipeTableViewCell.m#L256) method. A fair amount of the swiping logic is implemented in this here and the code is pretty clear and understandable.

Other great soruces of inspiration are TeehanLax's [UITableViewCell-Swipe-for-Options](https://github.com/TeehanLax/UITableViewCell-Swipe-for-Options) or runmad's [RMSwipeTableViewCell](https://github.com/runmad/RMSwipeTableViewCell).